# java : when is this method called : getTableCellRendererComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In order to set the color for a specific table cell, I should create a custom TableCellRenderer which has the following method : `getTableCellRendererComponent`.

when is this method called : `getTableCellRendererComponent` ?

just when a `JTable` is drawn for the first time ?

In case I have a set of buttons  and a jtable on a jframe, and each button when pressed will cause a certain number of cells in the table to be colored, how can I cause this method `"getTableCellRendererComponent"` to be called when I press on the button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fired when the table is first rendered but should be called on all cells when either a [fireTableCellUpdated](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableCellUpdated%28int,%20int%29) or any of the other "fire*" methods are called.  I'm under the impression that you're using a class that extends AbstractTableModel (DefaultTableModel?) at which point these methods should be fired when you update a particular value of a table model.

An example of using custom cell renderers can be found at [Example Depot](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/CustRend.html).  The getTableCellRendererComponent will be called when a cell is brought in to view and when a model update occurs.

*Addendum*: I just noticed one other part to your question, *when is the getTableCellRendererComponent called?* This is called for every visible cell in the table that must be rendered.  Think of it this way, if you are using a JLabel internally as your renderer, you would return the JLabel as configured for displaying that cell only.  It will be reused on the next cell for rendering it.  Easiest way to think of it is a visual template that you want your cell to look like, you configure it on the getTableCellRendererComponent call, and return it.  The calling framework renders it to the screen buffer as an "image" (for lack of a better term) then is reconfigured for the next cell and rendered again.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to forgot for when/how/where is/are TableCell(s) updated or not then look for prepareRenderer best example as I see [camickr blog](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/)

EDIT: for better/valuable hepl please edit your post and add your code

Answer (score 0):

> when is this method called :
>   getTableCellRendererComponent ?

This method will get called when the UI component gets displayed/rendered for your view the very first time.

> To set colors in cells of a JTable

1. Hope you are using the custom `DefaultTableCellRenderer`. If so, then you can globalize the JLabel in your custom CellRenderer and then set its background color upon button click based on the row, column index.
2. Else you can use the `DefaultTableColumnModel` which you have defaultrenderer/set customrenderer which will be renderered for each of the cell. Using which you can set the background color of the cell.

> ```
> TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(vColIndex);
> col.setCellRenderer(new MyTableCellRenderer());
> ```

Refer: [Simple example to demonstrate usage of TableCellRenderer](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-09/03-qa-0928-jtable.html)

Comment: The DefaultTableModel has nothing to do with renderering other than specifying the Class of the data so the appropriate renderer can be used by the table. There is NOT a default renderer for each cell. YOu can not specify the cell color in the TableModel.

Comment: -1 for a completely wrong first sentence (answering the "when"), another -1 for incorrectly bringing the model into play (as Rob already mentioned), a -1/2 for tying the config to a specific implementation of a renderer (any component will do). Would suggest you first learn go into learning rounds ;-)

Comment: @Camickr - I'm sorry that I have wrongly mentioned the DefaultTableModel instead of DefaultTableColumnModel. I have edited my post to correct those.
@kleopatra -

Comment: @kleopatra - Thanks for your feedback. 
I suppose the first answer for "when" question is correct. To technically explain we can say that **paintCell** method of **BasicTableUI** calls the **prepareRenderer** of **JTable** which inturn calls the **getTableCellRendererComponent**. So practically the paintCell gets called when we view the cell for the first time. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: still wrong - nothing special to the _first_ painting round. Plus it can get called by other clients and other needs (f.i. when measuring size requirements) downvoted