# Jtable Appearance: How to write a code with jtable properties that can be use to multiple jtables to have a similar appearance?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, properties, jtable

I am working with a simple crud with 5 tables, I already change the properties of Table_1 like (background color, foreground color, row height and etc.) What I want is that my Table_2, Table_3 and other tables to be look like the Table_1.

I have tried to create a custom TableCellRenderer
This is my code:

```java
package com.table.design.Default;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class StrippedTable implements TableCellRenderer {

    private TableCellRenderer mWrappedRenderer;

    public StrippedTable(TableCellRenderer pWrappedRenderer) {
        mWrappedRenderer = pWrappedRenderer;
   DefaultTableCellRenderer DEFAULT_RENDERER = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable pTable, Object pValue, boolean pIsSelected,
            boolean pHasFocus, int pRow, int pColumn) {

        Component c = mWrappedRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(pTable, pValue, pIsSelected, pHasFocus,
                pRow, pColumn);
        if ( pTable.isCellSelected(pRow, pColumn) == false ) {
            c.setBackground(colorForRow(pRow));
//            c.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.foreground"));
        } else {
//            c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 242, 242));
//            c.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionForeground"));
        }
//      setting global table properties
            pTable.setRowHeight(45);
            pTable.setShowVerticalLines(false);

        return c;
    }

    protected Color colorForRow(int row) {
        return (row % 2 == 0) ? new java.awt.Color(245, 245, 245) : Color.WHITE;
    }
}
```

is it ok to add the code

```java
//      setting global table properties
            pTable.setRowHeight(45);
            pTable.setShowVerticalLines(false);
```

to

```java
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable pTable, Object pValue, boolean pIsSelected,
            boolean pHasFocus, int pRow, int pColumn) {

        Component c = mWrappedRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(pTable, pValue, pIsSelected, pHasFocus,
                pRow, pColumn);
        if ( pTable.isCellSelected(pRow, pColumn) == false ) {
            c.setBackground(colorForRow(pRow));
//            c.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.foreground"));
        } else {
//            c.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 242, 242));
//            c.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionForeground"));
        }

//      setting global table properties
            pTable.setRowHeight(45);
            pTable.setShowVerticalLines(false);

        return c;

}
```

because it is working.. and i use this code to my tables to have the same properties

```java
TableModel s = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        StrippedTable cellRenderer = new StrippedTable(jTable1.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class));      
        jTable1.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, cellRenderer);
```

Thank you very much!!

-------EDITED------

I worked another class which extends jtable,

```java
package com.table.design;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class CustomTable extends JTable {

     public CustomTable(TableModel model, JScrollPane scrollpane) {
        super(model);
        getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new customHeaderRenderer());
        customTableProperties(scrollpane);
    }

    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {


        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        if (isCellSelected(row, column) == false) {
            c.setBackground(colorForRow(row));
        }

        return c;
    }

    protected Color colorForRow(int row) {
        return (row % 2 == 0) ? new java.awt.Color(245, 245, 245) : Color.WHITE;
    }

    private void customTableProperties(JScrollPane sp) {

        setForeground(new java.awt.Color(100, 100, 100));
        setShowVerticalLines(false);
        setFont(new Font("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        setIntercellSpacing(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));
        setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(242, 242, 242));
        setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));
        setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        setRowHeight(45);
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        setFocusable(false);
        setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        /**
         * *** JscrollPane*******
         */
        sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        sp.getViewport().setBackground(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));
        sp.setOpaque(false);


    }

    /**
     * Code for JtableHeaderRenderer
     *
     */
    public class customHeaderRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

        public customHeaderRenderer() {

            setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            setAutoResizeMode(0);
            setFont(new Font("Open Sans", Font.BOLD, 15));
            setForeground(new java.awt.Color(95, 95, 95));
            setOpaque(false);
            getTableHeader().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth(), 65));
            getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
            getTableHeader().setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 0, 2, 0, new java.awt.Color(235, 235, 235)));
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setText(value.toString());
            return this;
        }

    }


}
```

Then I will call the table like this

```java
private static CustomTable customTable;
private DefaultTableModel tbm;

tbm = (DefaultTableModel) customTable.getModel();
customTable = new CustomTable (tbm, /*Jscrollpane*/);
```

Is my code above correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally bad practice to modify parent component's appearance from cell renderers (mostly because they are called every time a cell update happens like stated in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6424791/3184968)).

In your case, I would simply create another class that extends JTable with a constructor that calls the desired super's constructor and then applies desired changes.

Your new class would look something like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class JCustomTable extends JTable {
    public JCustomTable(/* parameters of your desired JTable constructor */){
        super(/* parameters of your desired JTable constructor */);
        //setting desired global table properties
        setRowHeight(45);
        setShowVerticalLines(false);
    }
}
```

Now just use JCustomTable or whatever you want to call it anytime you would normally use a JTable object.

---

Much like in your first case, it isn't a good practice modifying other objects from within another one. In this case, it would be best to leave the custom table's constructor with a fingerprint like this (I added a few words to the first part in order to improve clarity):

```
CustomTable(TableModel)
```

The JScrollPane settings can, again, be done in the same way as JCustomTable, in order to keep the code object-oriented and generally cleaner.

Comment: So I would simply call it like this?? `JCustomTable mytable  = new JCustomTable(/* any parameter */);` or `JTable mytable  = new JCustomTable(/* any parameter */);` ?

Comment: I've edited my question above and added my class that extends JTable, is it correct?

Comment: I have extended the original answer.